# Fonts Corrupted in Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, fedora-17

So I imported ubuntu-font-family folder using application Fontmatrix. It did so & integrated them well.  However after that something bad happened.

Plus I can't see any documents containing special characters, for instance, the heart, bullets etc...
From the terminal:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH7ab.jpg]

plus many crylic fonts have been corrupted:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ZWX.jpg]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you run `sudo fc-cache -v` after adding the fonts?  I think Fontmatrix does this for you however, so it's possible there's something else going on here.

Comment: yes I have done it several times even restarts :(  Can I redownload them & overwirte or something